# WTF does WTF represent in the WebKit code base?

Tags: c++, webkit, chromium

I downloaded [Chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium)'s code base and ran across the [WTF namespace](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/wtf).

```
namespace WTF {
    /*
     * C++'s idea of a reinterpret_cast lacks sufficient cojones.
     */
    template<typename TO, typename FROM>
    TO bitwise_cast(FROM in)
    {
        COMPILE_ASSERT(sizeof(TO) == sizeof(FROM), WTF_wtf_reinterpret_cast_sizeof_types_is_equal);
        union {
            FROM from;
            TO to;
        } u;
        u.from = in;
        return u.to;
    }
} // namespace WTF
```

Does this mean what I think it means? Could be so, the `bitwise_cast` implementation specified here will not compile if either `TO` or `FROM` is not a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_Structures) and is not (AFAIK) more powerful than C++ built in `reinterpret_cast`.

The only point of light I see here is the nobody seems to be using `bitwise_cast` in the Chromium project.

Comment: Probably a good idea to quote the "NO WARRANTIES" part.

Comment: @KennyTM please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45844/is-the-tag-wtf-acceptable for a discussion of how to tag this question

Comment: Wow, that class is not described by "Web Template Framework." It's just a convenient abbreviation.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It’s short for **W**eb **T**emplate **F**ramework and provides commonly used functions all over the WebKit codebase.

Comment: as in C++ templates doing common stuff :)

Comment: any way of cloning that library?

Comment: Citations please. Does it do templating like Mustache or JSP?

Comment: @adib No, the "template" really refers to C++ templates and nothing else. See https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/SourceDirectory and https://webkit.org/blog/6161/locking-in-webkit/ (for WebKit sources) and https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/wtf/README.md (for Blink source).

Answer (score 5):

It is to avoid the strict-aliasing optimization problem:

[gcc, strict-aliasing, and casting through a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906365/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-casting-through-a-union)

Answer (score 2):

> Could be so, the bitwise_cast implementation specified here yields undefined behaviour if either TO or FROM is not a POD

If FROM or TO are not POD types, the compilation would fail with current C++ standard
because you wouldn't be able to put them in union.

Comment: Not sure. If your class contains a pointer-to-member, it's not a POD but it still can go in a union, I think.