# Convert pointer to float?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a `unsigned char*`. Typically this points to a chunk of data, but in some cases, the pointer IS the data, ie. casting a `int` value to the `unsigned char*` pointer (`unsigned char* intData = (unsigned char*)myInteger;`), and vice versa.

However, I need to do this with a `float` value, and it keeps giving me conversion errors.

```
unsigned char* data;
float myFloat = (float)data;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't, at least not easily. Without some magical hacks, this will never contain valid information, unless the input Is in the correct IEEE format.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII unless you know something sneaky that I don't (which is not that unlikely considering this is C++) you can do it pretty easily.

Comment: Is `sizeof(unsigned char *)` equal to `sizeof(float)` on your platform?  If not, what are you expecting this to do, exactly?  (Never mind the horribly undefinedness of the behavior in general...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports it (GCC does) then use a union.  This is undefined behavior according to the C++ standard.

```
union {
    unsigned char* p;
    float f;
} pun;

pun.p = data;
float myFloat = pun.f;
```

This works if `sizeof(unsigned char *) == sizeof(float)`.  If pointers are larger than floats then you have to rethink your strategy.

See wikipedia article on [type punning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) and in particular the section on [use of a union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union).

GCC allows type punning using a union as long as you use the union directly and not typecasting to a union... [see this IBM discussion on type-pun problems](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpm1%2Fm1rhpun.html) for correct and incorrect ways of using GCC for type punning.

Also see wikipedia's article on [strong and weak typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) and a well researched article on [type punning and strict aliasing](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/).

Comment: This is not an uncommon use of unions, however in C++ this results in undefined behavior on two counts: First it accesses an inactive member of a union (i.e., it accesses a member other than the one that was last set). Second, if it works as expected then it violates strict aliasing, accessing an object of one type (unsigned char*) through a glvalue of an unrelated type (float).

Comment: Doesn't strict aliasing involve referencing the same memory location with pointers to fundamentally different types?  That's not what's going on here.  See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906365/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-casting-through-a-union.

Comment: The strict aliasing rule is "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:" (3.10p10) This code is accessing the stored value of an `unsigned char *` object through a glvalue of type `float`. This case is not covered by any of the types listed by the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: I see you are right, so although it might be common and a compiler might support it, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @bames53: thanks for your comments, I've edited my answer to include your input.

Answer (score 4):

bit_cast:

```
template <class Dest, class Source>
inline Dest bit_cast(Source const &source) {
    static_assert(sizeof(Dest)==sizeof(Source), "size of destination and source objects must be equal");
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Dest>::value, "destination type must be trivially copyable.");
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Source>::value, "source type must be trivially copyable");

    Dest dest;
    std::memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof(dest));
    return dest;
}
```

Usage:

```
char *c = nullptr;
float f = bit_cast<float>(c);
c = bit_cast<char *>(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

The only correct way to use a given variable to store other data is to copy the data byte-wise:

```
template <typename T>
void store(unsigned char * & p, T const & val)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned char *) >= sizeof(T));

    char const * q = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&val);
    std::copy(q, q + sizeof(T), reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p));
}
```

Usage:

```
unsigned char * p;
store(p, 1.5);
store(p, 12UL);
```

The matching retrieval function:

```
template <typename T>
T load(unsigned char * const & p)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned char *) >= sizeof(T));

    T val;
    char const * q = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&p);
    std::copy(q, q + sizeof(T), reinterpret_cast<char *>(&val));

    return val;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto f = load<float>(p);
```

Comment: I think that your `load` declaration is off. You don't specify a return value.

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned char* data;
float myFloat = *(float*)data;
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting an `&`? If the `float` data is *in the pointer itself* you should write `&data`.

Comment: This would be undefined behaviour, even if written correctly.

Comment: I would bet this is not what the OP actually wants - they just did not know how to ask the question

Comment: @AdrianCornish: actually he stated it pretty clearly... "the pointer IS the data, ie. casting a `int` value to the `unsigned char*` pointer [...] I need to do this with a `float` value".

Comment: Why the downvote? This is *exactly* what the question asked for, UB or not. Fact is, this works, with multiple compilers. One response to what the standard says is undefined behavior is to give that behavior a well-defined response.

Comment: @DavidHammen: "exactly what the question asked" - it's not. Say `data` above contains 1234... the question asks for the bytes storing 1234 to be reinterpreted as a `float` value, not for whatever other unspecified bytes happen to be at address 1234 to be reinterpreted (which is what this answer does).  It's a less common requirement, but quite clearly stated.

Comment: I downvoted because this does not at all solve the described problem. This accesses the pointed-to data as though it were a float when the question is how to access the _pointer_ as though it were a float. It's the difference between `float f = *(float*)data;` and `float f = *(float*)&data;`. Also these casts have undefined behavior and should not be used.

Comment: @bames53: This does do exactly what the questioner asked. Sometimes that supposed pointer is not a pointer. It's really a float. This is an old C-style hack. It is undefined behavior, but it nonetheless is widely used and it works on many systems. I don't use it, I don't condone it, but I see it often enough. Think of it as equivalent to the union hack `union UnionHack {char * ptr, float fval};` , which oftentimes also involves undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidHammen again, this answer does `float f = *(float*)data;` and not `float f = *(float*)&data;`. The former does not do what the question asks, whereas the latter does.

Comment: @bames53 : You're correct, as is Matteo Italia. It needs to be `&data`, not `data`. And it is UB. Using `memcpy` would be better. Even better would be not to do this at all.