# Working with a union of structs in C

Tags: c, unions

Say I have the following types:

```
typedef struct TYPEA
{
    int type;
    char[12] id;
} TYPEA;

typedef struct TYPEB
{
    int type;
    int value;
} TYPEB;
```

I want to use create a union of these types and 'int', so that I can access the "type" int without needing to know whether TYPEA or TYPEB is stored in the union (the value of int lets me determine which is actually stored there). I can't get the right syntax though.

My union:

```
typedef union MEMBER
{
    int type;
    struct TYPEA a;
    struct TYPEB b;
} MEMBER;
```

The union is accessed via:

```
typedef struct WRAPPER
{
    union MEMBER* member;
    struct WRAPPER* next;
} WRAPPER;
```

Questions:

1. (With 'w' as a pointer to an allocated WRAPPER struct) Accessing using `w->member->a.id` gives "request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union.
2. Can I assign a pointer to an already malloc'd TYPEA/B to w->member directly? Or does a union need to be malloced specially?

Thanks.

Comment: `w->member` is still a pointer. You can't use the `.` operator on it.

Comment: member is a pointer, so why do you think you can access type w/o a pointer de-reference (->)?

Comment: there are some `;` missing, so it appears.

Comment: sorry, question 1 is meant to read: w->member->a.id, not w->member->type. I'm assuming this is the way because the union is not of pointers. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Use `w->member->type`.
2. You need to allocate the `union` specifically.

One note that may be a point of misunderstanding is that the `union` holds EITHER the `int`, or `TYPEA`, or `TYPEB`, so in particular you cannot rely on your `int type;` in the union to tell you which `struct` the union holds.

**Edit to respond to question in comments:**

You probably want something like this:

```
struct TYPEA {
  char data[30]; // or whatever
};

struct TYPEB {
  double x, y; // or whatever
};

struct some_info {
  int type; // set accordingly
  union {
    struct TYPEA a;
    struct TYPEB b;
  } data; // access with some_info_object.data.a or some_info_object.data.b
};
```

Comment: So even though TYPEA and TYPEB structs have an int in the first positions, there's no way to access it without knowing which type I'm working with?

Comment: Is malloc for `TYPEA` or `TYPEB` needed after mallocing `struct some_info`?

Comment: @Arthur No.  The members of `data` are not pointers so `sizeof(data)` is at least the larger of `sizeof(struct TYPEA)` and `sizeof(struct TYPEB)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You defined the `member` field as a pointer, so you should use
   `w->member->type` instead of `w->member.type`.
2. You should `malloc` the union type. When you allocate a union, you'll get a structure that  has a `sizeof` equal to the largest element in the union. If you try to copy structures into union pointers, you'll mess up the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

`w->member.type` should be `w->member->type` because `w->member` is a pointer.

I don't know off the top of my head whether C will let you assign a `TYPEA*` or `TYPEB*` to a `MEMBER*` - somehow I doubt it.  You can always `(MEMBER*)` it, but I would consider recomposing the `struct`s to remove the `int` tag and instead declare one `struct` that includes the tag and a `union` of `TYPEA` and `TYPEB`.  The `struct`s ideally shouldn't need to be concerned with the fact that they're in a `union`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the code in my question:

[Union of structs with common first member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752149/union-of-structs-with-common-first-member)

Essentially, I do what you want but I'm using an inner struct (`contained` in the example) that's common to the two types. This struct can then be cast to gain access to the common elements of both types.