# C pointers and -O3 optimized semantic anomalies

Tags: c, gcc, g++, clang, compiler-optimization

Code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(uint64_t* pInst)
{
    *pInst = 0xffffffffff;
    *pInst = *(uint32_t*)&(*pInst);
    uint64_t Ret = *pInst;
    printf ("Ret=%lld\n", Ret);
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t a;
    a = 0;
    func(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

Build & Run:

```
gcc -O3 test.cpp and gcc -O2 test.cpp
./a.out 
Ret=0

gcc -O1 test.cpp and gcc -O0 test.cpp
./a.out 
Ret=4294967295
```

I expect the return value to be 4294967295.
I try g++, it works like gcc.
And I try clang, it works will.

Comment: clane == clang?

Comment: I think this is a violation of aliasing rules, so the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior for a strict aliasing violation in `*(uint32_t*)&(*pInst)`. If you really want to write programs with aliasing violations, then you need to compile with `-fno-stricit-aliasing` to disable optimization based on the strict aliasing rule (and that is compiler-specific, not guaranteed to work per standard).

Comment: Thanks @user17732522, I found that this problem is similar to this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906365/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-casting-through-a-union

Comment: `&(*pInst)` is just `pInst` (except it's not an lvalue).